# Devise invitable - How to add a Method to InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using the devise invitable gem: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

My App also has a controller: invitations_controller.rb, which starts with:

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
```

I'm allowing users to register with FB and would like to add a method to this controller:

```
def fb_create
  Rails.logger.info 'fb_createfb_createfb_createfb_createfb_createfb_createfb_createfb_createfb_create'
end
```

I tried adding this to my routes.rb file as so:

```
post  "/users/invitation/fb_create" => "invitations#fb_create"
```

But that failed. How can I add a route for this method?

Currently my routes has been using this for devise:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:invitations => "invitations", :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add. The reason for using devise invitable is bec you can't join the app unless you're invited which is how you land on this page in the first place. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'that failed'? Did it get into the Invitations controller and not find the right action? was the route not found? It would be good to post the relevant portion of the output of `rake routes` and to show us what your rails server logs show when you post to that URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:invitations => "invitations", :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations"} do
    post  "/users/invitation/fb_create" => "invitations#fb_create", :as => "invitation_fb_create"
end
```

that would generate invitation_fb_create_path helper method pointing to that action